# CAGradientLayer sometimes not rendering

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, calayer

I have a CAGradientLayer drawing in the background on viewDidLoad. It works some of the time, but then sometimes it just doesn't render anything persistently until I restart my computer. I can't figure out why some of the time it would work and then other times it won't. It will work lets say 5 builds in a row and then it will just stop rendering. No errors. Anyone have experience with this?

Background Layer Method:

```
+ (CAGradientLayer*) morningGradient {

UIColor *mornTop = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.843 green:0.722 blue:0.667 alpha:1.000];
UIColor *mornBottom = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.584 green:0.733 blue:0.945 alpha:1.000];

NSArray *colors =  [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)mornTop.CGColor, mornBottom.CGColor, nil];

NSNumber *stopOne       = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
NSNumber *stopTwo       = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.7];
NSNumber *stopThree     = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];

NSArray *locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:stopOne, stopTwo, stopThree, nil];

CAGradientLayer *headerLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
headerLayer.colors = colors;
headerLayer.locations = locations;

return headerLayer;
}
```

Draw Method:

```
-(void)drawGrad
{
NSLog(@"drawing gradient");
CAGradientLayer *bgLayer = [BackgroundLayer morningGradient];
bgLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
[self.view.layer insertSublayer:bgLayer atIndex:0];
}
```

ViewDidLoad:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[self drawGrad];
[super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation of `CGGradientCreateWithColors(colorSpace, colors, locations[])` you can read

> The `locations` array should contain the same number of items as the `colors` array.

**I'm assuming that the same is true for `CAGradientLayer` but can't find anything in the documentation.** I'm making this assumption because it makes sense. How would you really interpret two colors and three locations? What should be the color at the third location?

Change your code so that you pass the *same number of colors as locations*.

Comment: This sounds logical. I'll give this a shot- thanks! I imagined in my head that the third location was the blend point (so shifting it above 0.5 would shift where the two colors are 50/50 mixed like in photoshop with anchor points).

Comment: Thanks David, this worked. That was very frustrating- I feel stupid.

Answer (score 0):

create a custom gradient view with round rect of size 3, you need to add the QuartzCore framework and then follow the code below (.h file and .m file)

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface CustomGradientView : UIView

    @end


#import "CustomGradientView.h"
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@implementation CustomGradientView

    - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
    {

       CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

        UIColor *color1=[UIColor whiteColor];
        CGColorRef startColor =color1.CGColor;

        UIColor *color2=[UIColor redColor];
        CGColorRef endColor = color2.CGColor;

        drawLinearGradient(context, rect, startColor, endColor);


        CGPathRef p = [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:rect
                                                  cornerRadius:3] CGPath];
        CGContextAddRect(context, rect);
        CGContextAddPath(context, p);
        CGContextEOClip(context);
        CGContextClearRect(context, rect);

    }

    @end
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for the answer, unfourtunately I never got a chance to try it! Looks good though